# How to name a serverless aws lambda not to include the stage name?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

my lambda name shows up as device-service-dev-functionOne

my serverless.yml is as follows:

```
service: device-service

    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs10.x
      region: us-east-2
      logs:
        restApi: true
    functions:
      functionOne:
        handler: src/function-one.handler


    plugins:
      - serverless-pseudo-parameters
      - serverless-offline
      - serverless-plugin-typescript
```

how do I prevent the dev getting included in device-service-dev-functionOne?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify name in the function definition e.g. `name: my-function` to override the default name.

```
service: device-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: us-east-2
  logs:
    restApi: true
functions:
  functionOne:
    name: my-function
    handler: src/function-one.handler


plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
```